# Create method for Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

Can describe to me why my Iterator does not work. JDeveloper says that I must create a method for Iterator, but I don't have a clue what the program means with that. Therefore I ask for your help. The Program looks like this:

**TestOrder:**

```
package hej;

import java.util.*;

public class TestOrder {


public static void main(String[] args) {



OrderRegister orderregister = new OrderRegister();


Order order1 = new Order("123","Kop");
Order order2 = new Order("456","Salj");
Order order3 = new Order("789","Kop");


orderregister.addOrder(order1);
orderregister.addOrder(order2);
orderregister.addOrder(order3);

System.out.println(orderregister.sokOrder("123").getKopsalj());
orderregister.raderaOrder("456");
Order tmpOrder = orderregister.sokOrder("456");
if (tmpOrder == null) {
    System.out.println("Fungerar!");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Why u lie?");
}
System.out.println(orderregister.sokOrder("123").getKopsalj());
orderregister.sokOrder("123").setKopsalj("Salj");
System.out.println(orderregister.sokOrder("123").getKopsalj());



Iterator<Order> i=orderregister.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
}
}
```

**Order:**

```
package hej;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Order {
private String ordernr;
private String kopsalj;

public Order(String newOrdernr, String newKopsalj) {
    setOrdernr(newOrdernr);
    setKopsalj(newKopsalj);
}

public void setOrdernr(String ordernr) {
    this.ordernr = ordernr;
}

public String getOrdernr() {
    return ordernr;
}

public void setKopsalj(String kopsalj) {
    this.kopsalj = kopsalj;
}

public String getKopsalj() {
    return kopsalj;
}

public  String toString()
{
    return "Order: " + this.ordernr+", "+"Manover: "
                            +this.kopsalj;
}
}
```

**OrderRegister:**

```
package hej;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class OrderRegister {

private ArrayList<Order> orderArrayList;

public OrderRegister() {
    orderArrayList = new ArrayList<Order>();
}



// Lagg till Order

public void addOrder(Order newOrder) {
    orderArrayList.add(newOrder);
}




// Sok Order

public Order sokOrder(String ordernrSok) {
    Order tmpOrder = null;
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (i < orderArrayList.size() && !found) {
        tmpOrder = orderArrayList.get(i);
        if (tmpOrder.getOrdernr().equals(ordernrSok)) {
            found = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (!found) {
        tmpOrder = null;
    }
    return tmpOrder;
}



// Ta bort Order

public void raderaOrder(String ordernrRadera) {
    Order tmpOrder = null;
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (i < orderArrayList.size() && !found) {
        tmpOrder = orderArrayList.get(i);
        if (tmpOrder.getOrdernr().equals(ordernrRadera)) {
            orderArrayList.remove(i);
            found = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
}



// andra Orderuppgifter

public void setOrderUppgifter(String ordernr, String newKopsalj){
    Order order = sokOrder(ordernr);
    if (order != null) {
        order.setKopsalj(newKopsalj);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code snippet to what is really needed? Plus, did you try adding a method `iterator()` to your class? (or alternatively, have it *extend* `ArrayList` instead of wrapping one!)

Comment: What *exactly* does it say? Please add the exact error

Answer (score 3):

You need to let the `OrderRegister` class implement [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).
`T` is the iterator data type, which is `Order` in your case.
So you get:

```
public class OrderRegister implements Iterable<Order>
```

The `Iterable` interface, requires you to define an `iterator()` method which returns an [`Iterator<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) object. In your case you do not require to create such an class, as you can grab the iterator object directly from your `ArrayList`:

```
public Iterator<Order> iterator() {
   return orderArrayList.iterator();
}
```

Now you can use your class in this way:

```
for(Order order: orderregister) {
    System.out.println(order.getKöpsälj());
}
```

Note: your `while`-loop will also still work

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html.

For every iterator, you need to implement methods hasNext, next and remove.

Plus, your class orderregister doesn't have any method iterator(). You either need to inherit form a class that already has it implemented or you need to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

let OrderRegister implements the Iterable interface and implement iterator than()

there you just can delegate to orderArrayList.iterator()

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is this line:

```
Iterator<Order> i=orderregister.iterator();
```

because there is no method `iterator()` in your class `OrderRegister`.

Two solutions:

A) add the method `iterator()` (it could probably just do `return orderArrayList.iterator();`)

B) instead of wrapping an `ArrayList`, *extend* it!

```
public class OrderRegister extends ArrayList<Order> {
    // No more orderArrayList!
}
```